# Format the "stats" parameter of rsync

Tags: regex, shell, statistics, rsync

I am very new to scripts, but I am writing a little rsync script for my NAS. I am now trying to edit the output of the rsync "stats" parameter.

Because this parameter give a lot of details, and I only need the final results, I start by only keeping the part I want :

```
sed -e '/Number/,$!d' $log > tmp && mv tmp $log
```

So that output for now looks like this :

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7JWfA.jpg)

So then I would like to remove the kind of timestamp from each line :

```
sed -e 's,.*] ,,' $log > tmp && mv tmp $log
```

So now it looks like this (in Outlook, as I send this result by email) :

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6D7et.jpg)

So then, I thought I could add a new line. I have tried multiples possibilities, but it doesn't work the way I would like. I can't show you a 3rd picture though.

Would you have any suggestion for me :) ? Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks Lars for your answer. Your code did what I wanted, but the problem persisted.

Lucky me, I found my problem with outlook : https://naveensnayak.wordpress.com/2012/08/30/ms-outlook-messing-up-line-breaks/

So instead of adding a new line, I made a very little change to my code :

```
sed -e 's,.*], ,' $log > tmp && mv tmp $log
```

Because there is a whitespace after my bracket (]), and that I add a 2nd whitespace, now my file looks nice in Outlook.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a newline to a file with the echo command:

```
> cat test.txt
1
2
3 > echo -e "\n" >> test.txt 
> cat test.txt
1
2
3

>
```

- `-e` enables the backslash interpretation
- `"\n"` is interpreted as newline
- `>>` appends instead of overwrites

Comment: This only adds one new line at the end of my file, but I wanted to do so with every line.

Comment: To replace EVERY lineend with an additional second newline, you could do something like `sed "s/$/\n/g" test.txt`.  It matches the lineend ($) and inserts a newline (\n).